# Python file listing

Tags: python, filedialog

I'm trying to find all the files in a folder starting with 'msCam' and ending with an extension '.avi'. I manage to do so with the following code:

```
path = path_to_analyze
files = [i for i in os.listdir(path) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path,i)) and \
         'msCam' in i]
print(len(files))
for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".avi"):
            msFileList = [os.path.join(path, file)]
            print(msFileList)
```

But this stores only the last file found in the given 'msFileList' variable.

```
print(msFileList)
```

How can I pass all the files to be stored?

[image: View the output here]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
path = path_to_analyze
files = [i for i in os.listdir(path) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path,i)) and \
     'msCam' in i]
msFileList = [] #create and empty list
print(len(files))
for file in files:
    if file.endswith(".avi"):
        msFileList.appened(os.path.join(path, file)) #append result to list

print(msFileList)
```

Answer (score 2):

Does this do what you are looking for?

```
filepath = './'
matching_files = []
with os.scandir(filepath) as entries:
    for entry in entries:
        if entry.name.startswith('msCam') and entry.name.endswith('.avi'):
            matching_files.append(entry.path+entry.name)
```

Comment: It is a useful aprproach! Thank you! Actually it works fine too with a little modification, but I prefer Seyi Daniels answer, but I'm really thankful for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

Your list is overwritten with the latest value in every iteration. You have to use the inbuilt `.append()` method.

```py
path = path_to_analyze
files = [i for i in os.listdir(path) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path,i)) and \
         'msCam' in i]
print(len(files))

msFileList = [] # filenames will be appended in this list
for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".avi"):
            msFileList.append(os.path.join(path, file)) # using .append()
            # print(msFileList)

print(msFileList) # Whole List will be printed
```